# Completely remove MariaDB or MySQL from CentOS 7 or RHEL 7

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb, yum, rhel

I installed MariaDB on CentOS 7 but I had some problems with some configuration, now it is completely misconfigured.

Thus, I wanted to remove the MariaDB with “yum remove mariadb mariadb-server”, after that I reinstalled it with “yum install mariadb mariadb-server”.

Unfortunately, the configuration remains. It seems as if yum remove don’t delete all MariaDB Config-Files.

How can I remove MariaDB completely from CentOS 7?

Answer (score 104):

These steps are working on CentOS 6.5 so they should work on CentOS 7 too:

(**EDIT** - exactly the same steps work for MariaDB 10.3 on CentOS 8)

1. `yum remove mariadb mariadb-server`
2. `rm -rf /var/lib/mysql` If your **datadir** in **/etc/my.cnf** points to a different directory, remove that directory instead of **/var/lib/mysql**
3. `rm /etc/my.cnf` the file might have already been deleted at step 1
4. Optional step: `rm ~/.my.cnf`
5. `yum install mariadb mariadb-server`

[**EDIT**] - Update for MariaDB 10.1 on CentOS 7

The steps above worked for CentOS 6.5 and MariaDB 10.

I've just installed MariaDB 10.1 on CentOS 7 and some of the steps are slightly different.

Step 1 would become:

```
yum remove MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

Step 5 would become:

```
yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

The other steps remain the same.

Comment: handy one liner to purge:

sudo yum remove -y mariadb mariadb-server && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql /etc/my.cnf

Comment: // , Tested this on the CEntOS 7.5 Bento Vagrant Box, and it worked. Thanks, Ciprian.

Comment: Done this on Centos 7.6, everything ok. Thanks!

Comment: On centos-release-7-7.1908.0.el7.centos.x86_64  `yum remove mariadb mariadb-server` actually takes care for both client and server packages (version 10.4.11-1.el7.centos)

Answer (score 12):

To update and answer the question without breaking mail servers. Later versions of CentOS 7 have MariaDB included as the base along with PostFix which relies on MariaDB. Removing using yum will also remove postfix and perl-DBD-MySQL. To get around this and keep postfix in place, first make a copy of /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18 (which is what postfix depends on) and then use:

```
rpm -qa | grep mariadb
```

then remove the mariadb packages using (changing to your versions):

```
rpm -e --nodeps "mariadb-libs-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64"
rpm -e --nodeps "mariadb-server-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64"
rpm -e --nodeps "mariadb-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64"
```

Delete left over files and folders (which also removes any databases):

```
rm -f /var/log/mariadb
rm -f /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log.rpmsave
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
rm -rf /usr/lib64/mysql
rm -rf /usr/share/mysql
```

Put back the copy of /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18 you made at the start and you can restart postfix.

There is more detail at https://code.trev.id.au/centos-7-remove-mariadb-replace-mysql/ which describes how to replace mariaDB with MySQL

Answer (score 8):

systemd

```
sudo systemctl stop mysqld.service && sudo yum remove -y mariadb mariadb-server && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql /etc/my.cnf
```

sysvinit

```
sudo service mysql stop && sudo apt-get remove mariadb mariadb-server && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql /etc/my.cnf
```