# How to cleanly and safely uninstall mysql client on RHEL server?

Tags: mariadb, uninstallation, yum, rhel

On RHEL server, if I remember correctly, I installed mariadb client by running:

`yum install mariadb`

Now I want to safely and cleanly uninstall it, how do I do it?

I know that this task might be dangerous because uninstalling a software cleanly requires uninstalling its dependencies as well, but other software might be using those dependencies as well. it can be hard to tell which dependencies are still being used and which aren't.

I don't want to mess up things on server so I ask here first for correct instruction.

Comment: Related steps for CentOS (the community fork of RHEL): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362904/completely-remove-mariadb-or-mysql-from-centos-7-or-rhel-7

Answer (score 0):

Generally `yum remove` will take care of the dependencies.  If you run yum **without** `-y` you'll get to see what yum will do and can decide if it seems sane.  If I run `yum remove mariadb` it will decide that mariadb-server also needs to be uninstalled since the package it is dependent on is being removed.

You can also do rollbacks with yum. You can undo a yum install, but the tricky part is finding the right transaction ID.  See [How to use yum history to rollback](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/64069).